# Mixing animated markers with information windows on google maps?

Tags: google-maps

Trying to mix two examples together - animated markers with info windows.  I have written the following code and tested it.

The error message is "Cannot read property 'open' of undefined" - however I cannot see why this code would not work.

Can anyone provide some help on this please?

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MapDemo.aspx.vb" Inherits="MapDemo.MapDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        margin-left: -52px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>





      // If you're adding a number of markers, you may want to drop them on the map
      // consecutively rather than all at once. This example shows how to use
      // window.setTimeout() to space your markers' animation.

      var neighborhoods = [
        {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},
        {lat: 52.549, lng: 13.422},
        {lat: 52.497, lng: 13.396},
        {lat: 52.517, lng: 13.394}
      ];

      var markers = [];
      var map;

      var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
  'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
  'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
  'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
  '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
  'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
  'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
  'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
  'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
  'Heritage Site.</p>' +
  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
      });

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: 52.520, lng: 13.410}
        });
      }

      function drop() {
        clearMarkers();
        for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
          addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
        }
        window.setTimeout(SetInfoWindows,2000);
      }

      function SetInfoWindows() {
          for (var i=0;i < markers.length;i++){
              markers[i].addListener('click', function () {
                  infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
              });
          }
      }



      function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
          window.setTimeout(function () {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: position,
                  map: map,
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
          });


          markers.push(marker); 
          }, timeout);
          
    
      }

      function clearMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA23Z01YxR3TQCWrqOD77awx1vOv09a4-Q&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get another javascript error as well: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`.

The line that generates the `Cannot read property 'open' of undefined` messages is `infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);` in this code;

```
function SetInfoWindows() {
    for (var i=0;i < markers.length;i++){
        markers[i].addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
        });
    }
}
```

The two issues with that code are:

1. `infowindow` is not initialized
2. `markers[i]` is an issue, `i` is left pointing to `markers.length` (which is invalid)

To address these:

1. initialize `infowindow` inside the `initMap` function.
2. use `this` for the second argument of `infowindow.open` (it is a reference to the clicked marker inside the click listener function).

fixed `SetInfoWindows` function:

```
  function SetInfoWindows() {
      for (var i=0;i < markers.length;i++){
          markers[i].addListener('click', function () {
              infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
      }
  }
```

**updated code snippet:**

```css
#map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #floating-panel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 25%;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
      line-height: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    #floating-panel {
      margin-left: -52px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="floating-panel">
    <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var neighborhoods = [
      {lat: 52.511,lng: 13.447},
      {lat: 52.549,lng: 13.422},
      {lat: 52.497,lng: 13.396},
      {lat: 52.517,lng: 13.394}
    ];

    var markers = [];
    var map;

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
      '<div id="siteNotice">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
      '<div id="bodyContent">' +
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
      'Heritage Site.</p>' +
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    var infowindow;

    function initMap() {
      // initialize the infowindow variable once the API has loaded
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
          lat: 52.520,
          lng: 13.410
        }
      });
    }

    function drop() {
      clearMarkers();
      for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
        addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
      }
      window.setTimeout(SetInfoWindows, 2000);
    }

    function SetInfoWindows() {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    }

    function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        markers.push(marker);
      }, timeout);
    }

    function clearMarkers() {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      markers = [];
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```